# nameError: name 'request is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, view

I'm trying to build an absolute url with reverse but I get the above error.

Code:

```
def get_endpoint(payload):
  url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("app-start-conversation"))
  data = json.dumps(payload)
  response = requests.post(url, data, headers=head)
```

Urls.py:

```
path(
"api/v2/app/startconversations",
views.StartConversation.as_view(),
name="app-start-conversation,
)
```

I get the error

```
nameError: name 'request is not defined
```

How do I import request?

The reason I need the full url is because with reverse alone, when I run the app locally I get the following error and I do not want to hardcode 120.0.0.1:8000/ to the url.

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/api/v2/app/startconversations': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/v2/app/startconversations?
```

Comment: I believe you should use ```requests.build_absolute_uri(reverse("app-start-conversation"))```

Comment: Try this: def get_endpoint(request, payload):

Comment: requests does not have an attribute "build_absolte_uri".

Comment: it is `request` not `requests` and add request to the function like this `def get_endpoint(request, payload)`

Answer (score 0):

build_absolute_uri should be called by an HttpRequest instance. Should be something like:

```py
from django.http import HttpRequest

def get_endpoint(payload):
  request = HttpRequest()
  url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("app-start-conversation"))
  data = json.dumps(payload)
  response = requests.post(url, data, headers=head)
```

Comment: Do I need to configure host anywhere? 
I now get the following error:
`File "/home/osboxes/ndoh-hub/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 87, in _get_raw_host
    host = self.META['SERVER_NAME']
KeyError: 'SERVER_NAME'
`